# How to make algorithms more efficient?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I tried to solve the following problem :
Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

If you were only permitted to buy one share of the stock and sell one share of the stock, design an algorithm to find the best times to buy and sell.

But I was only able to come up with an `O(n^2)` solution. I understood the solution when I saw it but I wouldn't have been able to come up with the O(n) solution. Can I get some tips on optimizing my algorithms?

Comment: Experience, trial and error, lots of practice, read books, .... etc.

Comment: Hope you will get clue from here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stock-buy-sell/, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-stock-span-problem/

Comment: Check if you can find a solution in given order of complexities: `O(1), O(log n), O(sqrt(n)), O(n), O(nlogn), O(n^2)`.

Comment: What's your algorithm :)

Comment: Being lazy puts you in an excellent position: Think of the most simple procedure that plausibly solves the problem at hand. Take some small problem instances and solve them "by hand" or step through an implementation. Next, take one not so small problem instance, and observe where you think: _this has been done before_ or _there must be a simpler way to do this_.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is an algorithm with linear O(N) complexity.

you have to trace following index information

- best sell time
- best buy time
- lowest price time
- maximum profit

The idea is simple. First, Set 'best buy time' to 0. Iterate an array and change the 'lowest price time' index if index meets a lower share price. This is a potential timing that you can earn a higher profit.

Also, update a maximum profit when the difference between share[index] - share[min] is higher than current value. Keep in mind 'minimum share' index and 'buy time' are totally different.

c++ implementation

```
pair<int, int> bestTradeTime(vector<int>& shares){
   int min = 0;
   int buy, sell, maxProfit=0;

   for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
      //If minimum price is found, update it. 
      //In this case, there is no way the profit is higher than maxProfit
      if(shares[min] > shares[i])
        min = i;

      //When finding maximum profit, update it. 
      else if(shares[i] - shares[min] > maxProfit){
        maxProfit = shares[i] - shares[min];
        buy = min;
        sell = i;
      }
   }
   return make_pair(buy, sell);
}
```

Comment: I understand the O (n) solution.  The issue is that I wouldn't have been able to come up with it.  I would like to learn some tips for opritimizing algorithms.  Also, what was your thought process while doing this question?

Comment: In my case, I use 'think framework' when I solve a problem like above. First, Find a solution whether it is optimal or not. Second, think about more efficient way of solving problem.

Comment: Of course, the second step is a very hard process to find. If you think you are not a genius, you have to train a lot to come up with a good solution.

Comment: Solve a lot of algorithm problems as much as you can. Then, apply a technique which is used to solve a certain problem to a new algorithm issue. More specific...Is there the way of O(n) solution? I guess it probably exists. How can I Then how? Oh! I solved a problem which is closely related to this problem!.

Comment: I can use a stack to solve this problem. 'Stack' can store a previous information which may be used to solve a problem keeping a current information to solve an optimal answer. But in this case, I don't have to save past one. What I need is a minimum price to buy only!.  This is a kind of process I used to solve this problem.

Comment: If you come up with above idea, the problem is almost solved! What we have to do is how to implement this idea and make a clean code as much as possible. The important thing is having "what information is needed to solve this problem" in mind. And I recommend a book which can train this 'think framework' : "The Algorithm Design Manual"!

Answer (score 1):

Like many crafts, this is a matter of experience, I guess. In this particular case, a good hint towards a linear time solution is to look for some algorithm that maintains a constant number of variables which during a scan provide enough information to answer the question "from the sequence's start to the current position.
But even to that end, you need to understand what kind of information you look for.
A "strategic" approach would be to ask for helpful information from the solution to the problem:

1) you could answer the question in linear time if you had an array of maximum profits für each index as selling point(simply scan for the maximum).

2) you could compute the maximum profit for each selling point if you had an array of minimum value in the subarray ending at each index.

3) carrying the minimum value in the subarray ending at each index is easy in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple algorithm with *linear* `O(N)` complexity.
Imagine that you have an array with prices, e.g.

```
   3 9 1 7 2 5 8 4 0
```

you have to scan the array while tracking

```
 - best buy index
 - best sell index
 - lowest price index
```

read the current index (`i`) and  value (`price`), then check

```
 // do we have a lower price than ever?
 if (price < prices[lowest price index])
   lowest price index = i;

 // can we sell for a better price?
 if (price > prices[best sell index])
   best sell index = i;

 // shall we switch from the best buy index to the lowest price index?
 if (prices[best sell index] - prices[best buy index] < price - prices[lowest price index])
   best buy index = lowest price index;
   best sell index = i;
```

C# implementation:

```
private static Tuple<int, int> BestTimes(double[] prices) {
  int bestBuyIndex = 0;   // buy at the opening
  int bestSellIndex = 0;  // ...and sell it immediately (with profit 0)

  int lowestBuyIndex = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < prices.Length; ++i) {
    double price = prices[i];

    if (price > prices[bestSellIndex])
      bestSellIndex = i;

    if (price < prices[lowestBuyIndex])
      lowestBuyIndex = i;

    if (price - prices[lowestBuyIndex] >= prices[bestSellIndex] - prices[bestBuyIndex]) {
      bestBuyIndex = lowestBuyIndex;
      bestSellIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return new Tuple<int, int>(bestBuyIndex, bestSellIndex);
}
```

Test:

```
double[] prices = new double[] { 3, 9, 1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 0 };

Tuple<int, int> solution =  BestTimes(prices);

Console.Write($"Buy at {solution.Item1} (price {prices[solution.Item1]}) ");
Console.Write($"Sell at {solution.Item2} (price {prices[solution.Item2]}) ");
```

Outcome is

```
Buy at 2 (price 1) Sell at 6 (price 8)
```

Comment: This wasn't a question for a linear time algorithm (OP indicated that he already knows that solution), but for a structured approach to find such algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked to me in an interview and I came up with the following logic:

My idea was to make a suffix array to get the optimized price to sell stock.
So, if I buy the stock at `price[i]`, the optimum solution is to sell the stock in

```
value = max(price[i+1], price[i+2], ... , price[n-1]);
```

So, reverse traversing the array I found the maximum of the `price[(i+1) .. (n-1)]` in `O(n)` time. After this array is filled, I can just forward traverse the array one more time to calculate the maximum profit and return it. The complexity of this solution is `O(n)`.

Here is my C++ implementation.

```
// Assuming the prices vector to be the prices of stock at different time
// instances. Also, I have assumed that we have to buy within values
// prices[0..(n-2)] and sell within values prices[1..(n-1)].

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int max_profit(std::vector <int> prices) {
    int n = prices.size(), profit = 0, b = -1, s = -1;

    // sell[i] = the price at which you should sell when you buy the stock at
    // prices[i] = max(prices[(i+1)...(n-1)]);
    // position[i] = the position at which sell[i] is stored in prices[i].

    std::vector <int> sell (n-1), position (n-1);
    sell[n-2] = prices[n-1];
    position[n-2] = n-1;
    for(int i = n-3; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(sell[i+1] > prices[i+1]) {
            sell[i] = sell[i+1];
            position[i] = position[i+1];
        }
        else {
            sell[i] = prices[i+1];
            position[i] = i+1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(sell[i+1] - prices[i] > profit) {
            profit = sell[i+1] - prices[i];
            b = i;
            s = position[i+1];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Buy at position: " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sell at position: " << s << std::endl;
    return profit;
}

int main() {
    int profit = max_profit(std::vector <int> {3, 9, 1, 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 0});
    std::cout << profit << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The sad part was this question was given to me before the interview and when the interview started, we didn't even discuss this solution.

An interesting version of this question is to buy and sell two different stock in the pattern `Buy Sell Buy Sell` (we cannot do `Buy Buy Sell Sell`) and get the maximum profit.